# Inserting Mysql queries into array using wp_list_table class

Tags: wp-list-table

I try to make a plugin that can show a table (with rows) in wordpress by using  the `WP_List_Table` class.

In my "students" table Ive got

```
Fname,Lname,school,Class
```

I've already found a example where they use arrays and typing manual everything to the table, which then looks like this

```
var $example_data = array(


array( 'ID' => 1,'booktitle' => 'Quarter Share', 'author' => 'Nathan Lowell', 
               'isbn' => '978-0982514542' ),
        array( 'ID' => 2, 'booktitle' => '7th Son: Descent','author' => ' Hutchins',
               'isbn' => '0312384378' ),
        array( 'ID' => 3, 'booktitle' => 'Shadowmagic', 'author' => 'John Lenahan',
               'isbn' => '978-1905548927' ),
        array( 'ID' => 4, 'booktitle' => 'The Crown Conspiracy', 'author' => 'Michael',
               'isbn' => '978-0979621130' ),
        array( 'ID' => 5, 'booktitle'     => 'Max', 'author' => 'Mark Jeffrey',
               'isbn' => '978-0061988929' ),
        array('ID' => 6, 'booktitle' => 'Jack Wakes Up: A Novel', 'author' => ' Har',
              'isbn' => '978-0307454355' )
    );
```

So I was wondering about is it possible to make an maybe more arrays where I can type `Select * From table name`? Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rethink if creating a custom [wp_list_table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) & stuff is the way to go.

I can tell from experience wp_list_table isn't fun to work with.

Besides I think (as far as I can judge here) a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) (or multiple) would be the way to go for you.
This way you probably don't need queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to query database for arbitrary data via SQL.

I would be hesitant about this approach, as per other answer `WP_List_Table` is one of more questionable APIs. :) But if you get a start on data retrieval you can always reuse it in different context.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a solution !

I´ve tried this and it´s working

```
private function table_data()
    {
        $data = array();


                $sqlget = "SELECT * FROM elever";
        $sqldata = mysql_query($sqlget) or die('error getting');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        $data[] = array(
                    'id'          => $row['id'],
                    'fornavn'       => $row['fornavn'],
                    'efternavn' => $row['efternavn'],
                    'skole'        => $row['skole'],
                    'klasse'    => $row['klasse'],
                    );

        }        


        return $data;
    }
```

It´s much easier than I´ve expected. Just `SELECT * FROM elever` and then explain where Im going to place the `$row`´s inside the array

Comment: Sorry, but I have to down vote this solution. Notice that  `mysql_query()`, it's deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Why don't you use `$wpdb` to query the database as suggested by @Rarst? Please note the following statement from the Codex on `WP_List_Table`:  *"This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to change without warning in any future WordPress release."*

Comment: @birgire to be fair it was "private" so long that no one longer gives a damn, people just use it... :)

Comment: @Rarst, sure, I must admit I've used the class myself and ignored this notice as well ;-) But my main concern was the `mysql_query()` usage instead of `$wpdb`, but I will upvote the answer when the OP has updated it. I wonder how many plugins use the `WP_List_Table` class?  I tried to search for [`WP_List_Table site:plugins.svn.wordpress.org`](https://www.google.com/search?q=WP_List_Table%20site:plugins.svn.wordpress.org) but it didn't give any result. Maybe these pages are not all indexed?

Comment: I'll upvote this solutions because sometimes get_results is using TOO much memory to proceed a select query on a big table, plus if you'll ask get_results to return ARRAY_A  it will increase memory usage twice.